# kivy any script does not open window in Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, window, kivy

I asked the question in stack owerflow before but I guess my problem is at first a ubuntu problem. When I excute a kivy script (e.g. hello world) in a vitualenv the script runs without errors but I see no open window only a Python icon in the task bar and it is  am not possible top open window. I will attached the terminal output and the icon. I guess there is a problem with configuration: Can I get a tip on how solve the problem?

[image]

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/claus/.kivy/logs/kivy_22-02-18_1.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/claus/Python_Programm/Python_Ingo/kivy_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/claus/Python_Programm/Python_Ingo/kivy_venv/bin/python3"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 21.2.6'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'X.Org'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD REDWOOD (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-100-generic, LLVM 12.0.0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event6
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event6>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> range position X is 0 - 2000
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> range position Y is 0 - 1400
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] </dev/input/event6> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```